# Automating iOS tests with Docker

Tags: ios, docker, automation, appium

There's another post about this, but it's four years old. Is there any way to run iOS Appium tests using docker, I've seen this image: [quamotion/appium-docker-ios](https://hub.docker.com/r/quamotion/appium-docker-ios). But I think quamotion is a paid service with its own scripting language, and I'd like to run this for free (maybe just using some servers like DigitalOcean)

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/appium/appium

Comment: @PhilippSelenium it only mentions android, and as far as I know there are no emulators for iOS that run on linux or windows containers, I might be wrong.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, I always need(ed) a MAC and an iphone to do this, right.

Comment: The `quamotion/appium-docker-ios` image contains the standard Appium server, so you can use any scripting language to write your Appium tests for iOS devices.
It does use closed-source software from Quamotion for which you'll need a license, though.

Answer (score 0):

For running iOS tests Appium requires Xcode with the command-line build tool.
You may think of using Darwin docker image, but I doubt it is easy to install XCode there.

You can check [vagrant-box-osx](https://github.com/AndrewDryga/vagrant-box-osx), but it looks outdated.